# Why is this function behaving differently than I expected?

Tags: javascript

Recently, I wrote a javascript code by referring to the Python code, but the result did not come out as expected.

Here's the code.

```js
const languages = ['python', 'perl', 'c', 'java'];

for (let lang of languages) {
    if(lang == "python" || "perl") {
        console.log(`${lang} need interpreter`);
    } else if (lang == "c" || "java") {
        console.log(`${lang} need compiler`);
    } else {
        console.log("Not a support language.");
    }
}
```

This is the python code I was referencing.

```py
languages = ['python', 'perl', 'c', 'java']

for lang in languages:
    if lang in ['python', 'perl']:
        print("%6s need interpreter" % lang)
    elif lang in ['c', 'java']:
        print("%6s need compiler" % lang)
    else:
        print("should not reach here")

// python need interpreter
// perl need interpreter
// c need compiler
// java need compiler
```

I googled it but couldn't find it. so, please help me, Thank you in advance!

Comment: Lines like `if(lang == "python" || "perl") {` need to be `if(lang == "python" || lang == "perl") {`, otherwise you're doing `if("perl")` which will always be true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lang == "python" || "perl"
```

does not do what you want. Use

```
lang == "python" || lang == "perl"
```

Comment: Would be nice to explain what `lang == "python" || "perl"` actually evaluates to, as the OP seems to be a (very) beginner.

Comment: @RoboRobok I explained it in my answer

Answer (score 0):

The following expression:

```js
lang == "python" || "perl"
```

Evaluates to:

```js
<lang> == <'python' || 'perl'>
<'java'> == <'python'> ~ <non-empty string> OR <non-empty string> is <first non-empty-string>
<false> ~ <non-empty string> <double-equals> <different non-empty string> is <false>
```

This means that `'python'` will always be the value of the right-hand side. This is because the Logical-OR (`||`) is used as a short-circuit evaluation in JavaScript. If you have a chain of falsy-values, the first non-falsy value will be picked.

```js
// First truthy
let a = undefined || null || 0 || false || 'foo'; console.log(a); // foo

// First non-null
let b = undefined ?? null ?? 0 ?? false ?? 'foo'; console.log(b); // 0

// Assign: 0 || 1 = 1
let c = 0; c ||= 1; console.log(c); // 1

// Assign: 0 ?? 1 = 1
let d = 0; c ??= 1; console.log(c); // 1

// Assign: 0 || null = null
let e = 0; e ||= null; console.log(e); // null

// Assign: 0 ?? null = 0
let f = 0; f ??= null; console.log(f); // 0
```

It does not matter if you used double (`==`) or triple equals (`===`) here. As long as the `lang` does not equal `'python'`, the condition will always be `false`.

You can use [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check within a list of items. This feel more pythonic, so I would just go this route. It's simpler than `lang === 'python' || lang === 'perl'`; especially if the languages you need to check is a long list.

```js
const languages = ['python', 'perl', 'c', 'java'];

for (let lang of languages) {
  if (['python', 'perl'].includes(lang)) {
    console.log(`${lang} needs an interpreter`);
  } else if (['c', 'java'].includes(lang)) {
    console.log(`${lang} needs a compiler`);
  } else {
    console.log('Not a supported language.');
  }
}
```

#### tl;dr

Sometimes the syntax on one language appears very different in another.

- **Python:** `lang in ['python', 'perl']`
- **JavaScript:** `['python', 'perl'].includes(lang)`

Comment: This code what I wanted to implement. Thanks you I learned a lot.

Comment: @Choiman elaborated and fix some stuff

Answer (score 0):

Because your first condition is always true.

In Javascript, if(var) is always true, unless var is a falsy value `(0, null, undefined, '', NaN)`

Your conditions are `lang === 'python'` or `'perl'`, `'perl'` is not falsy, so it's always `true`

You should write it like:

```
if(lang === "python" || lang === "perl")
```

Also a good practice in Javascript is that it's better to use `===` instead of `==` as `==` will try to convert types to match and then compare, but `===` will check for exact match